# spring cloud data flow application properties / environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

Have a docker container running a single spring cloud data flow application. Up until version 2.7.2 of data flow, I was able to pass all the database url/username/password properties to the application by defining them as environment variables in the container.

The application has application.yml defined to fetch the properties from variables, like this:

```
appname:
  datasource:
    url: ${APP_DB_URL:jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433}
    password: ${APP_DB_PASSWORD:D3faultP4ss!}
    username: ${APP_DB_USER:sa}
```

As said previously these variables was able to be defined by just having them as env variables in the container, now this method doesn't seem to work anymore starting from data flow 2.8 upwards.

Setup is configured to automatically register the application to the spring cloud data flow after startup, with following logic

1st delete all old tasks

```
curl "http://localhost:9393/tasks/definitions/${APP_NAME}?cleanup=false" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" -X DELETE
```

2nd delete all old applications

```
curl "http://localhost:9393/apps" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" -X DELETE
```

3rd register application

```
curl "http://localhost:9393/apps/task/${APP_NAME}/${APP_VERSION}" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" -X POST -d "uri=file%3A%2F%2Fapp%2F${APP_JAR}&force=true"
```

4th register task

```
curl "http://localhost:9393/tasks/definitions" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" -X POST -d "name=${APP_NAME}&definition=${APP_NAME}"
```

APP_NAME, APP_VERSION and APP_JAR are env variables put into the container in the build phase.

The on schedule, daily, the job is triggered with the following call:

```
curl "http://localhost:9393/tasks/executions" -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}" -X POST -d "name=${APP_NAME}&properties=deployer.${APP_NAME}.local.workingDirectoriesRoot%3D%2Fapp%2Flogs&arguments=--date%3D$(date --date='yesterday' +\%Y-\%m-\%d)+--range%3D${range}+--dataSource%3DApplication+SourceProperty"
```

As said, until 2.7.2 version this worked, now when trying to update to 2.8 or newer the application tries to connect to the default database url defined in the application.yml. How can I override these using env variables?
And obviously if there's a better way to do the auto registration of the app, all tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.7.x used Spring Boot 2.3
Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.8.x used Spring Boot 2.4

There are changes to property names and the data source initialisation will override your configuration unless you disable autoconfiguration of datasources.

We suggest you move to latest Spring Cloud Data Flow and update your applications to Spring Boot 2.7.x
The you provide properties like:
`app.<appname>.spring.datasource.url` etc.

Comment: application is spring boot 2.7 now, I tried renaming the variables which define the db connectivity url to the app_<appname>_ prefix but they're still not getting set. It's still using the defaults from application.yml

Comment: Are you running in Kubernetes or Local? If Kubernetes you can use kubectl describe pod to see the environment variable and arguments sent to the app.

Add logging.level.root=debug to see the details of what it being processed.